# Unable to update R scripts in Processing

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing, update

I'm unable to update my R script on Processing.

Nothing happens after hit OK button. Those scripts under "Updatable" never get updated. Am I missing something?

(QGIS 2.18.21, Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon)

[image]